# crashing in UICollectionView endUpdates

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

I have a data manager (singleton class) that loads JSON from my backend service and then perform some caching in it, write it to disk, etc

so then I put this method inside a :

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("com.testing.serialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL), ^{
      //my method that does disk caching here
});
```

inside this method when everything is done, I have a UINotification using the following:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNewStoriesNotification object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
                        });
```

and inside the notification I do the following:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        if ([highlightItems count] > 0){
            //doing some computation to find the index path
            [weakSelf.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray];
        }

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

and it sometimes gives me this error:

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UICollectionView.m:2662
```

I am not sure why.. but my guess is that it has to do with my use of GCD and notification. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
Even if I remove the insertItemsAtIndexPaths: it still crashes at performBatchUpdates.. wonder why
```

Comment: You should get an additional message - you have an assertion failure, but the details of the failed assertion should also be visible. Is there anything else in the debugger, or if you have exception break points on, if you continue a few times you should see more.

Comment: It's probably the case that you've added a row but haven't updated the model.

Comment: @jrturton I have updated the model first before adding the row

Comment: Are you using a custom layout object? If so, it could potentially be because you have a supplementary view that is not associated with an ordinary view object.